# Unexpected import while importing module

Tags: javascript, import, es6-modules

I am trying to import 'setCORS' from a node module 'google-translate-api-browser' but i am getting the error `SyntaxError: Unexpected token {`

I already tried specifying type="module" in my main script file but it seems to have no effect.

```
import { setCORS } from "google-translate-api-browser";
//setting up cors-anywhere server address
const translate = setCORS("http://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/");

translate(original.textContent(), {to:'ne'})
  .then(res => {
  console.log(res.text);
})
.catch(err => {
  console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: Importing npm modules this way is only allowed in NodeJS, if you want to import modules from the web you need to use a relative path instead of the module name.

Comment: it's showing the same error even if i run it on a node server.

Comment: have you installed the package?

Comment: yes i installed it. but should i mention it on the package.json file too?

Comment: no that shouldn't be causing any issues at this stage. you mentioned you tried specifying `type="module"`. That is only a thing in HTML script imports, which node doesn't use. How are you running the code?

Comment: using npm start.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you installed the module on an incorrect path.....
In the command line try (make sure youre in the main parent directory):

```
1.rm -rf node-modules
2. npm install --save google-translate-api-browser
3. npm install 
4. import  the module: import {setCors} from "google-translate-api-browser"
5. Test it out
```